# Get facebook page restrictions (country, age) via Graph API - OpenGraphObjectRestrictions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to know if a Facebook page has age or country restrictions ?

I found this on facebook documention: [OpenGraphObjectRestrictions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/open-graph-object-restrictions)

But it seems not working. I get an error like that:

```
{
      "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (age) on node type (Page)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "ALXe8MDbLtc"
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to know if a Facebook page has age or country restrictions ?

Only if you have admin access to the page; with a page access token you can read the current page settings, including `AGE_RESTRICTIONS` and `COUNTRY_RESTRICTIONS`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/settings/

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.

I used a token with manage_pages permission and I get an answer that contains the AGE_RESTRICTIONS but not the COUNTRY_RESTRICTIONS.

...
{
      "setting": "AGE_RESTRICTIONS",
      "value": "Anyone (13+)"
    },
...
Do you know why ? I Does that mean the page has no country restrictions ?

Comment: Yes, looks like that’s the case. A page _needs_ to have an age restriction set, but country restrictions are optional, so it seems those get only returned if the page actually made any.